# Template does not load when calling helper

Tags: php, magento

So if I just have

```
<label for="customernumber"><?php echo 'Customer Number' ?></label>
```

and I proceed to the next page - everything is fine.

But if I call my helper, the browser loads for a while and then nothing happens. I stay on the same step as before clicking the button.

```
<label for="customernumber"><?php echo $this->helper('customer_number')->__('Your Customer number:') ?></label>
```

I also tried with

```
<label for="customernumber"><?php echo Mage::helper('customer_number')->__('Your Customer number:') ?></label>
```

I have the same problem with the back-end (when trying to add a custom field in the template of sales/order/view). If I have just `echo 'some text'` it's fine, but if I try to use the helper, the whole design of the page in the back-end messes up.

The `config.xml` relevant part for the helper:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <customernumber>
            <class>Package_CustomerNumber_Helper</class>
        </customernumber>
    </helpers>
   ...
```

**P.S.** if that is relevant for the aliases - this is how I get the request from the template, in the helper:

```
$custNum = $this->_getRequest()->getPost('customer_number');
```

Comment: is the helper alias `customer_number` define in your module's config.xml?

Comment: `Magento::helper()` will never work, try `Mage::helper()`

Comment: @OSdave - My mistake while I was typing here. Otherwise in the code I use `Mage::...`. And I updated my post, check it out.

Comment: Did you create a Package_CustomerNumber_Helper_Data helper?

Comment: @OSdave - I fixed all the aliases to be the same in the `config.xml` and in the template and in the `getPost()` to be `customernumber` and now I get the field as I want it.

So the problem was the aliases. I am just not used yet to all the conventions and strange things about underscores, capital letters, aliases and so on... Thanks for the hint that you gave me! ;)

Answer (score 0):

as you defined the helper alias as `customernumber`, you have to use it as it is, i.e. without the underscore:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('customernumber')->__('Your Customer number:') ?>
```